# Solve for $x$: $\sin(6x) = \pi/6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm not sure how to solve for x here:

$$
\sin(6x) = \frac{\pi}{6}
$$

I'm used to the result on the right hand side being a value on the unit circle and from there dividing that value by six for example. How do I go about solving for x here?

Comment: $x=(1/6)×sin^{-1}[π/6]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$6x$ = $sin^{-1} (\frac {\pi}{6})$

$\therefore$ $6x$ = $0.510695831 + 2k\pi$, $\pi - 0.510695831 + $ $2k\pi$

hence, $x$ = $\frac{0.510695831 + 2k\pi}{6}$, $\frac{\pi - 0.510695831 + 2k\pi}{6}$ where $n\in \Bbb Z$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin\theta = \sin \alpha => \theta = n\pi + (-1)^n(\alpha)$$ for an integral $n$

Hence we intend to solve: $$\sin(6x) = \sin(\arcsin(\pi/6)) => 6x = n\pi + (-1)^n(\arcsin(\pi/6))$$
for any integral $n$